# JavaScript add method to constructor function

Tags: javascript

Why can't I do the following?

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
  };
}

var me = new Person("Robert");
me.sayHello();
```

Output: `Uncaught TypeError: me.sayHello is not a function(anonymous function) @ index.html:20`

Comment: `new Person("Robert");`

Comment: Sorry updated the question to what I really meant.

Comment: why did you fix the original Q? ,..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate an instance of Person by calling it this way: `var me = new Person("Robert");`

What you wrote your constructor using the pseudoclassical instantiation pattern.  The way this works in code is that when you use the keyword `new` it calls Person with two added lines of code behind the scenes.
It turns your function into this:

```
function Person(name) {
  // The new keyword adds this line
  // var this = Object.create(Person.prototype);

  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    "Hi, my name is " + this.name;
  };

  // and this line
  // return this;
}
```

Without the `new` keyword you do not actually return anything from your function.

Other reasons why you may not be getting what you expect.  Your `sayHello` function just creates a string.  I assume you want to log this string to the console, so modify your function like so:

```
this.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
}
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
  };
}

var me = new Person("Robert");
me.sayHello();
```

Comment: I just posted a quick answer to your question while I updated it more thoroughly.  Does it answer your question better now?

Comment: ok updated code as you specified. getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: me.sayHello is not a function`

Comment: Mmm, I think I might have confused you.  Take another look at my answer, The bottom block of code is what you want

Answer (score 1):

A 'new' keyword creates temporary object 'this' in the context of your costructor function 'Person'. Without 'new' this refers to global object (most of the cases).

Calling: new Person("Somebody") returns this temporary object 'this' so you get object based on it.

Without keyword 'new', your constructor function just returns 'undefined' (if no any 'return' keywords in the body of a function).